# Let $X_n$ be a simple random walk in $\Bbb Z^d$. For all $n,m,k\in\Bbb N,x,y\in\Bbb Z^d$ $\Bbb P(X_{n+k}=y\mid X_n=x)=\mathbb P(X_{m+k}=y \mid X_m=x)$

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability, random-walk

I wrote the following proof and wanted to know if there is anything I can improve in terms of maths but also writing :

Let $S_n$ be a simple random walk in $\Bbb Z^d$. For all $n, m, k \in \Bbb N$, $x,y \in \Bbb Z^d$
$$\mathbb P (S_{n+k} = y \lvert S_n = x) = \mathbb P (S_{m+k} = y \lvert S_m = x).$$

Proof :  We have by definition of the SRW and that of conditional probability that
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb P (S_{n+k} = y \lvert S_n = x) &= \mathbb P \Bigg( \sum_{i=0}^{n+k} X_i = y \Bigg| \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x \Bigg) \\
    \mathbb P \Bigg( \sum_{i=0}^{n+k} X_i = y \Bigg| \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x \Bigg) &= \dfrac{\mathbb P \big((\sum_{i=0}^{n+k} X_i = y )\cap (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x) \big)}{\mathbb P (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x )} \\
    \mathbb P \Bigg( \sum_{i=0}^{n+k} X_i = y \Bigg| \sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x \Bigg) &= \dfrac{\mathbb P \big((\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} X_i = y-x )\cap (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x) \big)}{\mathbb P (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x )} 
\end{align*}
By independence of the steps $X_j,X_k$ for $j\neq k$, we get
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{\mathbb P \big((\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} X_i = y-x )\cap (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x) \big)}{\mathbb P (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x )} &= \dfrac{\mathbb P \big(\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} X_i = y-x \big) \mathbb P \big(\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x\big) }{\mathbb P (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x )}\\
    \implies \mathbb P (S_{n+k} = y \lvert S_n = x) &= \mathbb P \Bigg( \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} X_i = y -x\Bigg) 
\end{align*}
Since each step $X_j$ is identically distributed, $$\mathbb P \Bigg( \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} X_i = y -x\Bigg)=\mathbb P \Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i = y -x\Bigg) = \mathbb P (S_{k} = y -x \lvert S_0 = 0).$$

We get a value that is independent of $n$, meaning that $\forall n,m \in \Bbb N$ $$\mathbb P (S_{n+k} = y \lvert S_n = x) = \mathbb P (S_{m+k} = y \lvert S_m = x)= \Bbb P (S_{k} = y -x \lvert S_0 = 0).$$

I also have two questions :

1. I supposed that my random walk is starting at $X_0=0$, but it is not necessary right ?
2. In the 3rd equality, I divide by $\mathbb P (\sum_{i=0}^{n} X_i = x )$ but that quantity might be $0$ if it is impossible to reach $x$ from my starting point in $n$ steps, right ?

Comment: Too wordy and you actually need that $(X_1, \ldots, X_t)$ to be independent of $(X_{t+1}, \ldots, X_{s+t})$ for all $s,t$ (as opposed to just "independence of the steps $X_j, X_k$ for $j \neq k$").

Comment: Due to an unknown downvoter, who could be OP, I have deleted my legitimate answer. It would be more appropriate to also justify an answer downvote instead of just downvoting and leaving it there.